# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOutlets' of null in postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Getting
TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOutlets' of null when trying to chain requests in postman, I am using response from one API and trying to get response from it and chain values in the other API.

I am working on chaining of the API requests via POSTMAN. I was trying to get a value of a variable from response body to use it into other API requests under my collection

I took the JSON path from online JSON Path finder from the 1st API response.
**Test:**
Getting error for below script:

```
bodyData  = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(bodyData.data.customer);
console.log(bodyData.data);
console.log(Object.keys(bodyData.data)), console.log(bodyData); 
console.log(Object.keys(bodyData));
value = bodyData.data.customer.listOutlets.outlets[3]
.externalOutletnumber;
pm.globals.set("externalOutletNumber",value);
```

**Result:**

```
    "data": {
    "customer": {
    "listOutlets": {
    "outlets": [
    {
    "outletNumber": "297895732",
    "accountName": "ABDIHDISH",
    "externalOutletNumber": "1234-3356765",
```

**Console log:** Due to privacy issue, cannot share whole response but sharing the structure of the log printed.

```
{listOutlets: {…}}
listOutlets: {…}
outlets: [16]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}

{customer: {…}}
customer: {…}
listOutlets: {…}
outlets: [16]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
```

Response: [enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/br4e1.png)

**Error**
**After running the monitor I am getting this error:** TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOutlets' of null

Comment: What do you get when you log these to the console, sequentially, right before setting the value for your `value` variable? `console.log(bodyData.data.customer); // should be null`, `console.log(bodyData.data);`, `console.log(Object.keys(bodyData.data))`, `console.log(bodyData);` `console.log(Object.keys(bodyData));` Do you get the same result if you try using `bodyData["data"]["customer"]["listOutlets"]`?

Comment: @FiddlingAway - Thankyou for your response, I am getting below on my console - Test scripts - *bodyData  = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(bodyData.data.customer);
 console.log(bodyData.data);
console.log(Object.keys(bodyData.data)), console.log(bodyData); 
console.log(Object.keys(bodyData));
value = bodyData.data.customer.listOutlets.outlets[1].externalOutletNumber;
pm.globals.set("externalOutletNumber",value);*

Comment: Console logs:  
POST https "URL to my API"
200
4.30 s
 
{listOutlets: {…}}
listOutlets: {…}
outlets: [14]
 
{customer: {…}}
customer: {…}
listOutlets: {…}
outlets: [14]
 
(1) ["customer"]
0: "customer"
 
{data: {…}}
 
(1) ["data"]

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question, and to add the test - result pairs? For example: *I tried console.log(<variable>), and the console output was <console output>* . This is just so I (or any other SO user) can be sure that I properly understand your test results.

Comment: Hey @FiddlingAway - I have updated my question, could you please take a look now.